# React dom not updating with Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, store

I'm new to react-redux and I'm having an issue with a web-app I'm developing. The app should have a user log-in functionality, it should be able to fetch and display a list of games from a database api I made, and it should be able to display information for a specific game from that list when it's clicked.

I have the user log-in functionality working perfectly, but the game list and specific game details don't initially display in the browser. If I look in the redux devtools, the action is dispatched and returns the correct information to the state, and if I page-through the devtools (push the play button), the list will show up in the dom, and stay until I refresh the page. The same is true for the game details.

I'm not sure what is wrong. I tried adjusting the react components and containers I'm using, but nothing I can think of / found in other posts seems to work. Maybe it's a problem with how I have the initial state set up (I have a initial state in both the user-login reducer and in the games reducer)?

I'll post what I think are the relevant blocks of code in this post.

store/reducers/currentUser.js

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from "../actionTypes";

const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    isAuthenticated: false, //hopefully be true, when user is logged in
    user: {} //all user info when logged in
};

export default (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_USER:
            return {
                // turn empty object into false, or if there are keys true
                isAuthenticated: !!Object.keys(action.user).length,
                user: action.user
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

stor/reducers/games.js

```
import { LOAD_GAMES, SET_CURRENT_GAME } from "../actionTypes";

const initState = {
    current: {},
    list: []
}
const game = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_GAMES:
            state.list = action.games;
            return state
        case SET_CURRENT_GAME:
            state.current = action.game;
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default game;
```

store/reducers/index.js (the root reducer file)

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import currentUser from "./currentUser";
import games from "./games";
import errors from "./errors";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    currentUser,
    games,
    errors
});

export default rootReducer;
```

store/index.js (the store composition file)

```
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export function configureStore() {
    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer, 
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunk),
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f
        )
    );

    return store;
}
```

store/actions/games.js

```
import { apiCall } from "../../services/api";
import { addError } from "./errors";
import { LOAD_GAMES, SET_CURRENT_GAME } from "../actionTypes"; 

export const loadGames = games => ({
  type: LOAD_GAMES,
  games
});

export const setCurrentGame = game => ({
    type: SET_CURRENT_GAME,
    game
});

export const fetchGames = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return apiCall("GET", "api/games/")
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(loadGames(res));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(addError(err.message));
      });
  };
};

//WRITE A FUNCTION TO SET_CURRENT_GAME TO BE THE ID OF THE GAME THAT IS CLICKED ON.
export const getGameDetails = game_id => {
    return dispatch => {
        return apiCall("GET", `/api/games/${game_id}`)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(setCurrentGame(res));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(addError(err.message));
        });
    };
};

export const postNewGame = title => (dispatch, getState) => {
  return apiCall("post", "/api/games", { title })
    .then(res => {})
    .catch(err => addError(err.message));
};
```

React containers and components:
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {configureStore} from "../store";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Main from "./Main";
import {setAuthorizationToken, setCurrentUser} from "../store/actions/auth";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const store = configureStore();

if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  setAuthorizationToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // prevent someone from manually tampering with the key of jwtToken in localStorage
  try {
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwtDecode(localStorage.jwtToken)));
  } catch (e) {
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
  }
}

const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <div className="onboarding">
                <Navbar />
                <Main />
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

Main.js (houses the Hompage component which has the Gamelist container)

```
import React from "react";
import {Switch, Route, withRouter, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Homepage from "../components/Homepage";
import AuthForm from "../components/AuthForm";
import {authUser} from "../store/actions/auth";
import {removeError} from "../store/actions/errors"
import withAuth from "../hocs/withAuth";
import GameForm from "./GameForm";
import GamePage from "../components/GamePage";

const Main = props => {
    const {authUser, errors, removeError, currentUser} = props;
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact render={props => <Homepage currentUser={currentUser} {...props} /> } />
                <Route 
                    path="/signin" exact
                    render={props => {
                        return(
                            <AuthForm 
                                removeError={removeError}
                                errors={errors}
                                onAuth={authUser}
                                buttonText="Log in" 
                                heading="Welcome Back." 
                                {...props} 
                            />
                        )
                    }} />
                <Route 
                    path="/signup" exact
                    render={props => {
                        return(
                            <AuthForm
                                removeError={removeError}
                                errors={errors}
                                onAuth={authUser}
                                signUp
                                buttonText="Sign me up" 
                                heading="Join Weekly Matchup today." 
                                {...props} 
                            />
                        )
                    }} 
                />
                <Route 
                    path="/games/new" exact
                    component={withAuth(GameForm)}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/games/:game_id" 
                    render={props => {
                        return(
                            <GamePage 
                                currentUser={currentUser}
                                {...props} 
                            />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <Redirect to="/" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        currentUser: state.currentUser,
        errors: state.errors
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {authUser, removeError})(Main));
```

Homepage.js (the component that displays the GameList container)

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import GameList from "../containers/GameList";

const Homepage = ({ currentUser }) => {
    if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated) {
        return (
            <div className="home-hero">
                <h1>Welcome to the Weekly Matchup!</h1>
                <h4>Weekly Matchup is a web app that allows you to vote for which characters you think are favored to win in a one-on-one matchup in a variety of fighting games.</h4>
                <p>If you would like to vote for and comment on this week's matchups, please be sure to make an account by clicking the link below, or sign in!</p>
                <Link to="/signup" className="btn btn-primary">
              Sign up here
        </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="home-hero">
                <h4>Click on the games below to see this week's matchups.</h4>
                <GameList />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Homepage;
```

GameList.js (the container that calls the fetchGames action from the store to generate the list of games

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchGames } from "../store/actions/games";


class GameList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchGames();
    }
    render() {

        const { list } = this.props;
        let gameList = list.map(g => ( 
            <li className="list-group-item" key= {g._id}>
                <Link to={`/games/${g._id}`}>
                    {g.title}
                </Link>
            </li>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="row col-sm-8">
                <div className="offset-1 col-sm-10">
                    <ul className="list-group" id="games">
                        {gameList}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        list: state.games.list
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchGames })(
    GameList
);
```

I'll stop there because that's where the problem occurs for the first time. I am aware I have posted a lot of code, but I'm not sure what is relevant or irrelevant in this situation.

Comment: Does console.log(list) in GameList.js gives the result?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Hope this advice is helpful: questions on Stack Overflow are for posterity (i.e. for many readers for many years). With that in mind, we want them to be readable (no chatter, see above) and we want temporary links to be omitted. It is more of a Wikipedia-like resource than a help-forum - the latter works on the basis that each answer helps exactly one person, and we want to do better than that `:-)`.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the advice and for the edit of the original post. I will be more technical with my future questions and answers, following the suggestions you provided. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to update the state this way don't mutate directly
I find two payload `action.games` and `action.game` is that intentional or a typo?

```
import { LOAD_GAMES, SET_CURRENT_GAME } from "../actionTypes";

const initState = {
    current: {},
    list: []
}
const game = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_GAMES:
            return {...state,
                    list:action.game
                     }
        case SET_CURRENT_GAME:
           return {...state,
                    current:action.games,
                     }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default game;
```

Comment: thank you so much! Your answer was 99% correct (list: action.games and current: action.game). It works perfectly now!